# Safe/performant way to make nginx redirect /?p=123 style links

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to make nginx 301-redirect wordpress-style `foo.com/?p=123` style links to fixed URLs.

From [If is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and other docs, I gather that perilous `if` statements are the only way to redirect based on parameters, and I found that configuration like this seems to get the job done:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

location = / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    if ($arg_p = 4)  { return 301 /2012/12/hello-world; }
    if ($arg_p = 15) { return 301 /about;               }
    # ... a few hundred more lines like this
}
```

However, I guess that with this kind of config nginx will have to plow through all those `if` statements just to resolve a top-level `foo.com/` requests, which presumably isn't ideal.

What's the "right" way to hard-code a big list of redirects like this, while minimizing the danger/cost of `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first good idea would be to put the redirect rules in a separate file. This will make the main configuration considerably more readable. The file with the rules then could be included with the [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive.

Another good idea is to use [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) instead of `if`, since it has a neater syntax for defining long lists.

Let's say you decided to put the rules in `/path/to/redirect/rules.conf`. The contents of this file then would look like this:

```
# Each map defines the set of rules for one set of conditions.
# The blocks must be sorted in order of priority: every next
# map block has a higher priority than the previous one.
map $arg_p $p_condition {
    default "";

    4              /2012/12/hello-world;
    15             /about;

    # You can use regular expressions
    ~^1[6-9]$      /some/page;
}

# By combining the condition variables you can implement
# some sort of and/or/not logic in your rules
map "${arg_p}#${arg_q}" $pq_condition {

    # Note that it is necessary to inherit the result
    # of the previous map block to preserve them. And this
    # is where the priority of the blocks comes from
    default $p_condition;

    # The values of p _and_ q are 4 and 15
    4#15           /2012/12/hello-world;

    # The value of p is 5 _or_ the value of q is 16
    ~"^5#.*"       /another/page;
    ~"^.*?#16"     /another/page;

    # The value of p is _not_ 8 _and_ the value of q is 30
    ~"^[^8]#30"    /the/very/special/page;
}

# The final block is of the highest priority. It defines
# the variable, which value will be used as the URL for redirection
map $args $url_to_redirect_to {

    # Don't forget this important line
    default $pq_condition;

    # Here's another type of condition: check if the t variable
    # is present in the list of GET paramters
    ~^(&|\?)t=.*$  /yet/another/page;
}
```

Now all is left to do is to use the defined rules in the main configuration:

```
# Note that map directives must be placed out of the `server` block
include /path/to/redirect/rules.conf;

server {
    ...

    location = / {
        ...

        if ($url_to_redirect_to != "") {
            rewrite ^ $url_to_redirect_to? permanent;
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

At a first glance the cascade of the `map` blocks might look somewhat messy, but you'll see the advantages of this approach when you put a lot of rules in there.